# Unix - condition within condition

Tags: unix, ksh

I've been looking all over the place but couldn't find an answer.
In ksh, how do you do something like this:

```
while [ [ ! [ [ -n $var1 ] || [ [ -n $var2 ] && [ -n $var3 ] ] ] ] && [ ! [ [ -n $var1 ] && [ -n $var2 ] ] ] ]; do
    ...etc etc
done
```

or in pseudo/a bit easier way to see

```
while ((! ((var1 != none) or 
         ((var2 != none) and (var3 != none)))
      and
      (!((var1 != none) and (var2 != none)))) {
....
}
```

...essentially any kind of conditions that are grouped

I've found a lot on simple conditions like
    if [ -z $var1 ] && [ -n $var2 ]; then

but not like the one above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to use `ksh`'s `[[ ]]` syntax. `(` and `)` don't need to be quoted and you can use `&&` and `||` just as in C language. For example:

```
[[ ! ( -n $var1 && ( -n $var2 || -n $var3 ) ) ]]
```

Also, you don't need to double quote `$var` within `[[ ]]` which would make the code much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with the test  you want to perform.

- fragments like  `-n $var` will fail if `$var` is empty as it will be expanded to a single `-n`.

Using `-n "$var"` instead is the bulletproof version here.

- **and** is expressed with the `-a` operator **not** with `&&`
- **or** is expressed with the `-o` operator **not** with `||`
- the **grouping** operator is `()` not another nested `[]` construct

Applying this rules your expression would come closer to looking something like that:

```
[ ! ( -n "$var1" -o ( -n "$var2" -a -n "$var3" ) ) -a ! ( -n "$var1" -a -n "$var2" ) ]
```

Note that use of spaces is **mandatory** here.

Depending on escaping rules you might have to escape `(` and `)`.

As I don't know how those are handled in `ksh` I can't tell for sure if really necessary there, but the all shell proof version would look something like that:

```
[ ! '(' -n "$var1" -o '(' -n "$var2" -a -n "$var3" ')' ')' -a ! '(' -n "$var1" -a -n "$var2" ')' ]
```

Note that `[` is an executable usually located in `/usr/bin/` so there aren't any syntactic differences across different shells.

It's only different meta characters that you have to be aware of, when using `[` with a different shell.